# Covering a VIewController With another ViewController (NO animation or Transition)

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, swift3

this question may asked before but i can't find any related question thats why posting a new one

so i have 3 tabs and in tab3 i have user profile Tab 
in tab3 i wanna show loginViewController (if user haven't logged in yet) else i want  to show the default profile tab

i can pass a segue using `performSegue` or present a view controller like this :

```
 let loginPageView =  self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginVC") as! SignupViewController
 self.present(loginPageView, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

but i dont want that  , 
i wanna show a different VC at the place of Default VC if user haven't logged in yet  **without any animation or transition**

e.g.

**producthunt's iOS app**

if user's didn't logged in

[image]

and if he did logged in:

[image]

see the first image they are not presenting it as pop over or modal.
it seems like they do it on a same VIewController but i'm not sure. anybody can guide me here ?

Answer (score 0):

replacing current Viewcontroller with desired ViewController did the job

```
    let loginPageView =  self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginVC") as! SignupViewController
    var VCs =  self.navigationController?.viewControllers

    VCs?.removeLast() // here i removed the current VC

    VCs?.append(loginPageView) after that added the desired VC

    self.navigationController?.setViewControllers(VCs!, animated: false) // here i'm setting the viewcontrollers  with any animation.
```